# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: apache-tomcat-7.0.25

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, web-deployment, noclassdeffounderror

While deploying my application to a tomcat server I'm facing following errors:

```
2013-06-14 07:54:36 ErrorLogger [ERROR] Job (DEFAULT.NearByRioDeJaneiro threw an exception.
org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception. [See nested exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.frrole.service.common.OAuthUtil]
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:224)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.frrole.service.common.OAuthUtil
    at com.frrole.service.common.City._getTweetsByQueryObj(City.java:357)
    at com.frrole.service.common.City.getTweetsByGeoLocSearch(City.java:340)
    at com.frrole.service.api.TwitterSearch.nearbyLocationSearch(TwitterSearch.java:148)
    at com.frrole.service.imports.jobs.NearByRioDeJaneiro.execute(NearByRioDeJaneiro.java:14)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
```

As it can be observed from this error log the main problem is with tomcat not being able to locate: `com.frrole.service.common.OAuthUtil` class. This class is referenced by the method `_getTweetsByQueryObj` in class `com.frrole.service.common.City`. Hence, somewhere while executing this method, tomcat is unable to locate OAuthUtil class. The OAuthUtil class has proper package statement defined in its code. The application also compiles successfully otherwise ws.war would not have been produced.

The confusing part is that `OAuthUtil` class is in same package (and directory) as `City` class. Below is a `ls` of directory tree in ws directory of tomcat's webapps folder.

```
root@servicesfrrole3:/usr/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.25/webapps/ws/WEB-INF/classes/com/frrole/service/common# ls -l
total 88
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12284 2013-06-14 13:15 City.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 21350 2013-06-14 13:15 DBUtil.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1064 2013-06-14 13:15 Messages.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2026 2013-06-14 13:15 OAuthUtil$_AccessToken.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2741 2013-06-14 13:15 OAuthUtil.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1710 2013-06-14 13:15 ReTweet.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1431 2013-06-14 13:15 SQLUtils.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  6397 2013-06-14 13:15 TimeAgo.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3363 2013-06-14 13:15 Tweet.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3730 2013-06-14 13:15 TweetUtil.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  5982 2013-06-14 13:15 TweetVO.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1328 2013-06-14 13:15 TwitterResults.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1941 2013-06-14 13:15 ViaTweet.class
```

**As it can be observed, clearly there is a OAuthUtil.class residing in the same directory as City.class**. The code compiles properly and runs perfectly on localhost which has Java 7 and Tomcat 7.0.40. The server has Java 7 and Tomcat 7.0.25 on server.

While deploying application, I'm simply compiling it on localhost and copying the ws.war file into webapps directory of server followed by rm -r of ws folder from previous application and finally restarting the server.

If anyone has any explanation of what is happening here, please provide some solution.

Comment: forgot when was this solution, but once needed to put the jar ( classes) to Tomcat's classpath. Wasn't any logical reason why, but there worked and at mine app/lib folder not. Give it a try

Comment: In fact `NoClassDefFoundError` can also be throwed if there is an exception when intializing static fields of your class. Do you have some?If yes, can you post the `OAuthUtil` code, or at the the static parts?

Comment: We are facing the same issue, it is just a different class. How did you had it resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clue is in the exception message:

```
"Could not initialize class com.frrole.service.common.OAuthUtil"
```

What has actually happened is that an error has occurred *previously* in some class initializer.  (Maybe the `OAuthUtil` class itself, or maybe some other class that it depends on.)  If you look back through the log file, you should see the exception.

Now you have executed some code that depends on that class that previously failed initialization.  The result is this exception.

If you can't find the previous exception in your log files, it is probably due to the exception being "squashed", or being lost when some thread died because your application hasn't defined a default uncaught exception handler.

Comment: Thank you for very clear explanation. But then why is application running on localhost and not on remote server?

Comment: I've no idea.  But I expect that the earlier exception / stacktrace will explain it.